# Why is the "Name and Address of Reporting Person" and "Signature of Reporting Person" not the same in this SEC filing?

Tags: sec

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1237860/000141809120000032/xslF345X03/wf-form4_158172921860528.xml

In the SEC Form 4 filing above, why is the reporting person *ROSENBLATT DAVID S*, while the signature of the reporting person is that of *Sean Edgett, Attorney-in-Fact*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sean Edgett, as mentioned in the signature, is an attorney-in-fact. This means that ROSENBLATT DAVID S has granted Sean Edgett a power of attorney (POA). A power of attorney (POA) is a legal document giving the attorney-in-fact (Sean Edgett) some powers to act for another person (ROSENBLATT DAVID S). In this case, ROSENBLATT DAVID S has apparently given Sean Edgett the power to sign the document on his behalf.